# Azure DevOps and private Docker registry

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I try to add a Service connection to a private Docker registry in Azure DevOps, it seems I have to provide a Docker Hub (Docker ID) user and password.

Why is that? I just want to push to our private Docker registry.

I tried putting in my Docker ID and using the service connection in Azure Pipelines, but I get permission denied.

Do you know of any guides to using Azure Pipelines with a private Docker registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To use any of Docker's tooling you need a Docker account.  Part of this is that Docker will use base images from Docker Hub to build images that may be stored in a private repository.
- For the Docker ID getting permission denied verify that you used the ID and not your e-mail.
- Microsoft and others have put together great documentation both Azure Pipelines and private Docker registries:
  [Introduction to private Docker container registries in Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-intro) (will help you make sure it is configured properly)
  [Accessing Azure resources from a Dockerfile](https://jessicadeen.com/how-to-access-private-azure-devops-repos-from-a-dockerfile/) (useful since you may be trying to do something similar in your build pipeline)